# How do you download an image which filename does not end with an extension?

Tags: javascript, node.js

If you right-click on any profile image on Github and `open image in new tab` you will see that it doesn't end with an extension

For example, here's the actual image of a user on github:

https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/170270?s=60&v=4

### Goal

I'm trying to add image saving functionality to my node.js app using `request` module:

```
// A proper image link (e.g. *.jpg)
let fileUrl_1 = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/06/20/03/15/pier-1467984_1280.jpg"

// Semi proper image link (e.g. *.jpeg?query)
let fileUrl_2 = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/371633/pexels-photo-371633.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260"

// Not a proper image link (e.g. filename[no extension]?query)
let fileUrl_3 = "https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/170270?s=60&v=4"

let parsedPath = pathModule.parse(fileUrl_1)
let fileName = parsedPath.base
let destinationPath = `C:\\test\\${fileName}`

let request = require("request")
request
  .get(fileUrl_1)
  .on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err)
  })
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(destinationPath))
```

### Problem

When I try to download images with normal paths like `fileUrl_1` it works fine, but if I try to download images like `fileUrl_2` or `fileUrl_3` shown above I get an error:

`ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\test\170270?s=60&v=4'`

BUT, if you just `right-click` / `save image as` on a "problematic" image in any browser, you will get a `save as` dialog window and will be able to save this image as `170270.jpg`

### Question

How do you download any image with node.js like the `save as` dialog window does (retrive the image even if it doesn't end with a proper extension)?

Comment: The server will send you the mimetype, you can derive the extension from there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's entirely up to you to choose the destination filename, based on whatever you want. There is no problem in retrieving the image - your only problem is you are trying to save it with an invalid filename.

The server response may include a [`Content-Disposition` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition#Directives), which may include a recommended default filename.

> The filename is always optional and must not be used blindly by the application: path information should be stripped, and conversion to the server file system rules should be done.

It should also include a [`Content-Type` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) from which you can derive a file extension, however this header may be incorrect.

> Browsers will do MIME sniffing in some cases and will not necessarily follow the value of this header

Or you can "sniff" the first few bytes of the response body and check for a known magic number to indicate the file type.

Comment: Thanks for the info! So I have to manually check if it contains `?` symbol, then remove everything after it, and then get the extension from the header and add it to the filename myself, right?

Comment: @Un1 you can do whatever you want.

Answer (score 2):

`pathModule.parse` is designed to parse **file paths**, not URLs.

The examples you have where it fails to provide a valid filename are those with a `?` in them.

Use a URL parser instead.

```
const url = require('url');

var fileName = url
  .parse(
    'https://images.pexels.com/photos/371633/pexels-photo-371633.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260'
  )
  .pathname.match(/\/([^\/]*)$/)[1];

console.log(fileName);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Even though node's path module also returns the path name (everything after the last slash `/`)  I suppose using a proper url parser would be more reliable. Thanks!

Comment: @Un1 — "everything after the last slash" includes the query string and fragment id, which is the problem.

Comment: Ahh, I see. You're using regex to get rid of the everything before the last slash, got it

Comment: You should use the `url` to get the path from the URL, and `path` to get the filename from the path. No regex needed.